# Spring framework - Context initialization failed - Out of memory space

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, out-of-memory

Last week I got a new laptop at my work and since then I can't make my dev environment to work.
I'm keep getting the following exception when running the server (tomcat 7).

I was trying to increase heap memory without any luck..

Please advice...I really don't know what to do.
Thanks
Zi

```
[localhost-startStop-1] **ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed**
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'friendController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.beepme.services.api.GenericApi com.beepme.controllers.FriendController.genericApi; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'genericApi': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.beepme.services.RouteService com.beepme.services.api.GenericApi.routeSvc; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'routeServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.beepme.services.RouteMatchingService com.beepme.services.RouteServiceImpl.routeMatchingService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'routeMatchingServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.beepme.components.RouteCache com.beepme.services.RouteMatchingServiceImpl.routeCache; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'routeCacheImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.**OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
```

Comment: What are you caching in heap?

Comment: Can you add more details? in order to help you better

Comment: how are you trying to increase heap space and to what amount?

Comment: I didn't have any problem on my old laptop, so my guess it something specific in my environment. I tried to run the service with those parameters(-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m) but it didn't help:(

Comment: What kind of details can help you? It's spring version 3.2.0

Comment: What are you doing in the "RouteCacheImpl.init()" for the System to get out of memory?

Comment: I had a mistake... I'm loading some data from the DB

Comment: I've found the line that get this exception.. After increasing the memory to 2Gb with -Xmx2048m it initialized successfully.. Thanks for your help!